# 400 Error while fetching from API using Axios in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

[image]I have a problem fetching API in react native using Axios. The web API is a bit complex with grant_type and that has been a huge problem. More also is there any configuration needed to be done on xcode to allow HTTP resource?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
    Text, 
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
    TextInput,
    StyleSheet,
 } 
 from 'react-native';
 import axios from 'axios';

 export default class Login extends Component {
     constructor(props){
         super(props)
       this.state =  {
                username:'',
                password:''
         };
     }
     componentDidMount(){
         const data={
             grant_type: 'password',
             client_id:'RxPadApp',
             username: this.state.username,
             password: this.state.password,

         }
         axios.post('http://192.168.210.159:3000/api/2019/token',
             data
         )
         .then((response)=>{
             console.log(response);
         }).catch((error)=>{
             console.log(error);
         });
     }
     render(){
         return(
            <View style ={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.logCon}>
                    <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login</Text>
                </View>
                <Text style= {styles.label}>Username</Text>
                <TextInput 
                  style={styles.textbox}  
                  autoCapitalize="none"
                  placeholder="Username"
                  onChangeText= {(username)=>{
                       this.setState({username});
                  }
                  }
                  value={this.state.username}/>

                <Text style= {styles.label}>Password</Text> 
                <TextInput 
                  style={styles.textbox}  
                  placeholder="Password"
                  secureTextEntry={true}
                  onChangeText= {(password)=>{
                       this.setState({password});

                  }

                  }
                  value={this.state.password}
                />

                <View>
                    <Text>Forgot password</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signin}

                >
                    <Text style={styles.signinText}>Sign In</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.signupTextCont}>
                    <Text style={styles.signupText}>Not an APG Member? </Text>
                    <Text 
                    style={{fontWeight:'bold', color: '#1A78B9'}}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignupScreen')}
                    >
                    Sign Up
                    </Text>
                </View> 
            </View>
         );
     }
 }
```

This is the url: http://192.168.210.159:3000/api/2019/token and this is the grant_type:  grant_type=password&username=mary2@ApgDemo.ca&password=demodemo&client_id=RxPadApp which is in the body of the postman. The header includes content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded. 
I intend to login to a homepage.

Meanwhile looking at the console. it displays error code 400 which implies there is a problem with the code or the URL is not bound correctly due to the grant_type specified in the body of the post. Find attached for your perusal. [image]

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: So, what is the excact problem?

Comment: it is displaying error from console and I don't know how to redirect to homepage. Although I have not created it

Comment: maybe you can try setting content-type in header. 

axios.post('/my-url', 'my message text', {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
});

Comment: Thak @ducmai how do I pass user's inputs (username and password) from the form?

Comment: Please I need assistance is not a very descriptive title. Be a good citizen and take time to write a meaningful title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your postman example you're sending the request with content-type "text/plain", so you could set the corresponding request-option in your axios request:

```
const data = 'grant_type=password&username=mary2@ApgDemo.ca&password=demodemo&client_id=RxPadApp';   
axios.post('http://192.168.210.159:3000/api/2019/token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
});
```

Comment: I want the username and password be input entries from users as I am going to create more users. How do I go about it? Thank you

Comment: Please how do I pass data to it